# An example of Nilpotent endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be the endomorphism defined by :
$$f : \mathbb R_n[X]→\mathbb R_n[X],\ P↦P(X+1)-P(X)$$
How can we prove that $f$ is nilpotent with index equal to $n+1$ ?, by another meaning :
$$f^{n+1}=0,\ and \ f^n≠0$$

Comment: Show $f$ reduces degree by one.

Comment: Can you write your proof dear friend, i don't understand !!

Comment: What @AnginaSeng means is that if $P \in \mathbb{R}_n[X]$ and $\deg(P) > 0$ then $\deg(f(P)) < \deg(P)$. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial) if you don't know what the degree of a polynomial is. You should prove this fact and use it to conclude that $f$ is nilpotent of index $n+1$.

Comment: For that matter, this is the reason that the calculus of finite differences can tell us whether a sequence of numbers, say integers, is just of the form $x_n = f(n)$ for polynomial $f$ with integer (well, maybe rational...) coefficients. If the polynomial is monic of degree $n,$ the last nonzero sequence is all $n!$

Comment: @AchrafBOURASS You tried computing some powers of $f$? What is $f^2(p(X)) = f(p(X+1)-p(X))$? And what about $f^3(p(X))$?